# Force dependency on gradleApi()

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

My gradle plugin requires the gradle API. Thus I'm using the gradleApi() dependency of Gradle 2.7.

```
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    ...
}
```

Gradle 2.7 comes with junit 4.12 causing me a lot of trouble. That's why I force junit version 4.11. If I show the dependency tree, it doesn't appear. But during test execution using gradle test, it's using junit 4.12.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()

        force 'junit:junit:4.11', 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3'
    }
}
```

I know that the wrong verson is used because of a powermock error message, which only happens with junit 4.12. If  I use gradle 2.0, the build works fine.

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: Field 'fTestClass' was not found in class org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.
```

How can I exclude depencies from gradleApi()?

Comment: Did you try https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies ?

Comment: Yes, but then it will exclude all dependencies from that artefact. I need to exclude a specific version, since I want to keep the other one. Usually a force would achieve this, but this is not working for gradleApi().